# KVO not working for class property

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-observing

I'm trying to understand key value observation in iOS but I think I'm not doing something correctly.
As an idea, I tried to add an observer to a view controller's property (a view connected with an IBOutlet). This view (tableIndicator) is animated so I wanted to see if I can get the observer to react when the view's frame changes.

So I did the following, inside the view controller's viewDidLoad:

```
[tableInidicator addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:nil];
```

`tableIndicator` is my view/class property, I'm adding the view controller (self) as the observer, 0 for the default options and frame as the key value being observed.

Then, I'm waiting to see if this function is triggered as the frame changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    NSLog(@"value changed");
}
```

...but nothing happens.

I'm not necessarily looking for fix to this code since it serves no purpose other than for me to understand it and I would be really grateful if someone could point out to me what I'm doing wrong. Some good examples/tutorials would be awesome too.

The ones I found ( http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.ro/2009/02/kvo-and-iphone-sdk.html / http://nachbaur.com/blog/back-to-basics-using-kvo ) did not cover such cases. They were only observers applied to a class to watch for one of its properties, not for the property of a (custom)object inside a class, something that I think would be more useful for me.

Thank you in advance

[edit]**For those who will miss my comment on the accepted answer:**

Changing a view's center will apparently not trigger an observer for the frame property. You have to change the frame itself.

Comment: As far as i understand from your question if tableindicator is ur viewcontroller then go for NSNotification instead of KVO

Comment: I know how to use NSNotification. I'm trying to use KVO for this so I can better understand this technique.

Comment: I know this is a really old question that was answered long ago, but I wanted to add a comment for the sake of others who may find it.  What you should realize about the "frame" of a view in UIKit is that it is synthesized from the values found in the "bounds" and the "center".  If you want to do KVO on the position or size of a view, you are usually better off observing the bounds or center and not the frame property.  The frame property will only fire KVO notifications if you change it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your IBOutlet is connected correctly, probably the tableIndicator ivar points to a nil.
Consider this simple code below, it works. It just creates a window, add a red square on it, then register using KVO the object to be notified for frame change. Finally it instantiates a button: each time you tap on it the frame is reduced by size, and the notification is triggered correctly (you will see the message in the debug console).
So you must check your code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize v = _v;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    _v.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.window addSubview:_v];

    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    b.frame=CGRectMake(0, 300, 40, 10);
    [b setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(changeFrame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_window addSubview:b];

    [_v addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];

    return YES;
}

-(void)changeFrame {
    CGRect _f = self.v.frame;
    _f = CGRectInset(_f, 20, 20);
    _v.frame=_f;
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Observing...");
}
```

Comment: My view controller and its view are working, everything is connected. I tried to implement the KVO code on a finished project so the problem is not there. I will look at your code now, thank you!

Comment: I tried your code on a new project and it worked, but not for my project. I did manage to find out the problem though, it was because I was basically chaning the view's center and not specifically its frame. When I forcefully change the frame, it worked and I was notified. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is something which is not entirely clear about your code. Is `tableIndicator` a custom class derived from `UIView`? The method `observeValueForKeyPath` should be defined inside that class, and it would be then called. But I am not sure this is the best approach.

In general, a sounder approach is to define your controller (not your view) as an observer. In this case you do:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"view.frame" options:0 context:nil];
```

from inside the controller at some point; `observeValueForKeyPath` would also be defined as a method in the controller.

Comment: nope, tableIndicator is not a class, it's a simple UIView that moves around while I scroll trough a table. Your observation is very valuable though, I was actually wondering how to observe a custom object's value. Unfortunately, applying your solution doesn't seem to be working, which is weird... I even tried it for a simple boolean property and I still can't get any reaction. I think I'll go read some more, I'm definitely doing something wrong here